# How to convert a group of Hexadecimal to Decimal (Visual Studio )

Tags: hex, decimal

[image: Group of Hex in textbox]

[image: eg: using smaller groups of values]

**I want to retrieve like in Pic2, the values in Decimal.** ( hardcoded for visual understanding)

This is the codes to convert Hex to Dec for 16 bit:

```
        string H;
        int D;

        H = txtHex.Text;
        D = Convert.ToInt16(H, 16);
        txtDec.Text = Convert.ToString(D);
```

however it doesn't work for a whole group

Answer (score 0):

So the hex you are looking at does not refer to a decimal number. If it did refer to a single number that number would be far too large to store in any integral type. It might actually be too large to store in floating point types.

That hex you are looking at represents the binary data of a file. Each set of two characters represents one byte (because 16^2 = 2^8).

Take each pair of hex characters and convert it to a value between 0 and 255. You can accomplish this easily by converting each character to its numerical value. In case you don't have a complete understanding of what hex is, here's a map.

```
'0' = 0
'1' = 1
'2' = 2
'3' = 3
'4' = 4
'5' = 5
'6' = 6
'7' = 7
'8' = 8
'9' = 9
'A' = 10
'B' = 11
'C' = 12
'D' = 13
'E' = 14
'F' = 15
```

If the character on the left evaluates to *n* and the character on the right evaluates to *m* then the decimal value of the hex pair is *(n x 16) + m*.

You can use this method to get your values between 0 and 255. You then need to store each value in an `unsigned char` (this is a C/C++/ObjC term - I have no idea what the C# or VBA equivalent is, sorry). You then concatenate these `unsigned char`'s to create the binary of the file. **It is very important that you use an 8 bit type to store these values. You should not store these values in 16 bit integers, as you do above, or you will get corrupted data.**

I don't know what you're meant to output in your program but this is how you get the data. If you provide a little more information I can probably help you use this binary.

Comment: can you refer to my edited question. Thanks. @William Rosenbloom

Comment: @Jojoleo Ok so you just use the values between 0 and 255 then. You still calculate those values as I described, but I guess then you just print them.

Comment: the problem I am having is splitting the characters when a **blank space** is being detected. @William Rosenbloom

Answer (score 0):

You will need to split the contents into separate hex-number pairs ("B9", "D1" and so on). Then you can convert each into their "byte" value and add it to a result list.

Something like this, although you may need to adjust the "Split" (now it uses single spaces, returns, newlines and tabs as separator):

```
var byteList = new List<byte>();
foreach(var bytestring in txtHex.Text.Split(new[] {' ', '\r', '\n', '\t'},
     StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
{
    byteList.Add(Convert.ToByte(bytestring, 16));
}
byte[] bytes = byteList.ToArray(); // further processing usually needs a byte-array instead of a List<byte>
```

What you then do with those "bytes" is up to you.

Comment: I get this error :
**Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: startIndex **
for  this coding
`byteList.Add(Convert.ToByte(bytestring, 16)); `
@Hans Kesting

Comment: @Jojoleo - Convert.ToByte throws that ArgumentOutOfRangeException when "bytestring" is empty. You need to make sure that you feed it just the real character pairs. Maybe it's enough to use an overload of Split that uses `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`.

Comment: Okay, the values I have in bytestring is **07\r\nDC** using the edited codes ( if u refer to pic1, its the last value of row 1 and first value or the second row)
With **07\r\nDC**, where**\r\n** are not within the 0 through F it resulted in this error **Additional non-parsable characters are at the end of the string.** @Hans Kesting . Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: @Jojoleo - you needed to split on more than just the space. I changed the code.

Comment: I pretty much got it using array... and last element appears
Its pretty stupid if I am gg to print the array like this 
`txtAnswer.Text = Convert.ToString(B[0,0])+ " " +Convert.ToString(B[0,1]).....; `@Hans Kesting

Comment: @Jojoleo - so you need to go through all indexes? A perfect job for a `for` loop (or two - you appear to have a two dimensional array).

Comment: Yup, all of the 2000 rows of values. 
`for (int row1 = 0; **row1 < 2000**; row1++)
            {
                for (int col1 = 0; col1 < 16; col1++)
                {
                    txtAnswer.Text += Convert.ToString(B[row1, col1]);
                    txtAnswer.Text += " ";

                }
                txtAnswer.Text += "\r\n";
            }`

I put it as row1<300 and it took about a min to show up. I am not sure about row1<2000... looks like the system hanged

Comment: @Jojoleo - don't use plain string concatenation for so many items, use StringBuilder. See http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/stringbuilder.html